# Using external class methods inside the imported module

Tags: python, qt, class, module, pyqt

My python application consists of various *separate* processing algorithms/modules combined within a single (Py)Qt GUI for ease of access.

Every processing algorithm sits within its own module and all the communication with GUI elements is implemented within a single class in the main module. 
In particular, this GUI class has a progressbar ([QProgressBar](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qprogressbar.html)) object designed to represent the current processing progress of a chosen algorithm.
This object has `.setValue()` method (`self.dlg.progressBar.setValue(int)`).

The problem is that since `self.dlg.progressBar.setValue()` is a class method I cannot use it inside my imported processing modules *to report their progress state within their own code*.

The only workaround I found is to add `progressbar` variable to definition of each processing module, pass there `self.dlg.progressBar` inside the main module and then blindly call `progressbar.setValue(%some_processing_var%)` inside the processing module.

Is this the only way to use outer class methods inside imported modules or are there better ways?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. I think this approach somewhat breaks software engineering principles (e.g. [single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)). In single responsibility principle, each module is only in charge of its assigned task and nothing else. If we consider UI a separate layer, so your processing modules shouldn't have anything to do with the UI layer.

In this case, your modules should have a method called `publish_progress(callback)` which `callback` is a function to be called for each progress step ([more info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming))). Then, in your UI layer define a function which is given an integer (between 0 to 100) and updates the progress bar. Once you've defined it, you should register it with `publish_progress` method of your modules.

```
def progress_callback(prg):
    self.dlg.progressBar.setValue(prg)
```

Registering it:

```
my_module.publish_progress(progress_callback)
```

Calling the callback in your module:

```
progress_callback(0)
...
# do something
...
progress_callback(20)
...
# do something
...
progress_callback(100)
```

Comment: @hi-im-frogatto I think I'm getting the idea, but still there are a few things I don't understand. **1. Main (GUI) module:** a) If I have to define the `progress_callback` inside my GUI class, why there is no `self` in the definition? b) where in the main code I have to put registering statement? **2. Processing module(s):** a) should I define `publish_progress` inside a processing function or as a separate method? b) Based on your kind reply, all the real work is done by `progress_callback`, which I import from the main module. Then what should this `publish_progress` method do?

Comment: @Vasily **1.a:** No. `progress_callback` isn't supposed to be a _method_ of `Main` class. It's instead a local function that can be defined inside one of the main's methods. **1.b:** Registering statement could be right after the UI initialization (or somewhere else). **2.a:** It could be a method of the processing class. (or a function of the module). **2.b:** `publish_progress` is just a register function/method and does nothing else. If something is still unclear, feel free to ask.

Comment: @Vasily This approach is kind of Callback pattern. [Check it out at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)).

Comment: @hi-im-frogatto yes, I've read [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)), [this](http://code-maven.com/function-or-callback-in-python) and [this](http://curiosityhealsthecat.blogspot.ru/2013/07/using-python-decorators-for-registering_8614.html) but I still cannot understand `the_caller` - `the_callback` relation in my case. I see that you've already explained it all in a great detail, but since this is a very first time I'm using this it's still hard to implement. But I see that it is a very important thing to learn so I won't give up no matter how dumb I am ;)

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40140531/report-progress-to-qprogressbar-using-variable-from-an-imported-module#40140793) I opened another question with a simple but detailed version of the code. I believe it could be a bit easier if I can display a whole picture. Thank you for you help, I'm sure I'll be laughing at myself when I finally understand it completely.